# Find how many non-blank rows in worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, python-3.x, win32com

I have a simple macro enabled workbook and have entered the following **data** into it:

```
    A    B    C
1   A1   B1   C1
2   A2   B2   C2
3   A3   B3   C3
```

I have included a library called *win32com* in my Python script that interprets VBA code. My  **code** is:

```
import os
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('spreadsheet.xlsm'). ReadOnly=1)
wb.Worksheets('Main').Activate()
numRows = wb.Worksheets('Main').Rows.Count
print(numRows)
```

The **output** for this is:

> 1048576

The **desired output** is:

> 3

Does anyone know the correct VBA to find the actual numbers of non-blank cells in my worksheet?

Comment: replace one line numrows= wb.Worksheets('Main').Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Thank you. It is saying invalid syntax on the '&'. I have also tried '+'

Comment: @techie Since Excel is being Late Bound, you can't use Enums (e.g. `xlUp` needs to be `-4162`), and because it's not in a `With` you need to define a Workbook for that `.Rows`  (You also can't leave it Implicit, because you're Binding Excel from another Application so the default behaviour is different)

Answer (score 0):

```
numrows=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Try the above code if it works for you

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't recognise 'Sheets' or 'xlDown'. This seems to be a common answer using xlDown so I can only assume it is the Python library that is causing the problem

Comment: This needs to be Fully Qualified in order to work in Java, and swap the Enum out for the number behind it: `numrow = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(-4121).Row`.  That said, this code will start at A1 and go down until it changes from Blank to Non-Blank cells - useless if you have blank rows in the middle of column A.  Starting at the bottom and working up (`numrow = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,1).End(-4162).Row`) is better

Answer (score 0):

You ask a couple of different questions in your question and title.

Bottom Row in Column A:

```
numRow= wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(wb.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count,1).End(-4162).Row
print(numRow)
```

> Starts at the very bottom of Column A of the first Worksheet, then uses `End(xlUp)` to find the first last non-blank entry.  Issues: Will return `1` if EVERY row has data, 65536 rows in a .xls file or 1048576 rows in an .xlsx or .xlsm file

Non-Blank cells in Column A:

```
numRow = xl.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb.Sheets(1).Columns(1))
print(numRow)
```

> Uses the Excel `COUNTA` function to count non-blank cells in the First Column of the First Worksheet

Non-Blank **Rows**, regardless of which Column is non-blank:

```
numRow = 0
For RangeArea In Union(wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23), wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)).EntireRow.Areas:
    numRow = numRow + RangeArea.Rows.Count

print(numRow)
```

> First, finds all Cells with Values and all Cells with Formula, then gets the rows that they are in.
>   If there are any blank-rows then this creates a Multi-Area Range, so we have to add up the number of Rows in each Area to get the total number of non-blank Rows in the Worksheet.